# Are user-level troubleshooting questions appropriate?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

Questions like: When Abode Reader plugin attempts to open web documents in IE8, sometimes a blank dialog box appears and the document fails to open.

Comment: Don't we already have questions like his, so why would they not be on-topic?

Comment: @Ivo, just checking. I didn't see any this specific.

Comment: Well your success with such questions will highly depend on how much information you supply and follow up when additional information is needed, but I don't see why these would be off-topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly, but only with more popular programs that have some chance of getting answered. (e.g. Microsoft Word, Excel, Adobe Reader..)

If it's a really obscure or less common program, I would refer people to the vendor-specific support sites.

Answer (score 5):

As long as Super User isn't bombarded to a {insert program here} bug tracker and if the questions aren't too trivial, I'd say they're on-topic...